# Extending a jQuery prototype

Tags: jquery

I have a method `addObject` on a jQuery prototype which I have done using `jQuery.fn.extend()`.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    addObject : function(objectKey){
        this[objectKey] = {};
    }
});
```

Now I want to add a method `addNewObject` to its prototype. I am trying to emulate the below scenario

```
function addObject(){
    ...
}

addObject.prototype.addNewObject = function(){
    ...
}
```

How is my addObject accessible with `new` keyword?

Comment: *"I have a method addObject on jquery prototype which I have done using jQuery.fn.extend()."* *Show* us, don't *tell* us.

Comment: `jQuery.fn.addObject.prototype.addNewObject = function()  {...`

Comment: What is expected result of `this[objectKey] = {};` ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `extend` you could use:

```
// insulate plugin in IIFE
(function() {
    // declare function
    function addObject(options) {
        return this.each(function(){});
    }
    // add prototypes
    addObject.prototype.addNewObject = function() {}

    // extend as plugin by passing function reference
    $.fn.addObject = addObject;


})(jQuery);
```

See  https://jqueryboilerplate.com/ for lots of information, guides , patterns etc for developing plugins